# How can I extract a substring from a string in Oracle, starting from a specific character?

Tags: oracle, substr

I need to extract a substring from a string in Oracle.

For example, I need to extract the string `"DHA-F-0046789"` from `"RA_PVAC000275994.From.INS012.To.DHA-F-0046789.File.1.2.xml"`.

I do not want to use the position of the characters to extract the substring because the substring I'd like to extract may be at different positions in the string. The text I wish to extract may be at the beginning of the string.

Sometimes the substring I wish to extract may be in the format `"F-DHA-sds89"` rather than `"DHA-F-0046789"`.

Comment: and the environment you use is...?

Comment: Is "To." and ".File" always wrapped around the string you want as a result? And yeah - the environment and language is essential to your question.

Answer (score -2):

select substr   (
&param,
instr(&param,'To.',1)+3,
instr(substr(&param,instr(&param,'To.',1)+3),'.',1)-1
)
from dual;